# name '_Unspecified' is not defined

Tags: pandas, csv

Simple CSV import, but am getting this error for some reason, cannot understand why?

```
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\train\Desktop\klopp.csv")
```

> > NameError: name '_Unspecified' is not defined
>
> Traceback..
>
> runfile('C:/Users/train/Desktop/Spring 2020/Taylor/practice.py',
>   wdir='C:/Users/train/Desktop/Spring 2020/Taylor') Traceback (most
>   recent call last):
>
> File "", line 1, in 
>       runfile('C:/Users/train/Desktop/Spring 2020/Taylor/practice.py', wdir='C:/Users/train/Desktop/Spring 2020/Taylor')
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\train\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 827, in runfile
>       execfile(filename, namespace)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\train\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder_kernels\customize\spydercustomize.py",
>   line 110, in execfile
>       exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)
>
> File "C:/Users/train/Desktop/Spring 2020/Taylor/practice.py", line
>   4, in 
>       data = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\train\Desktop\klopp.csv")
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\train\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 685, in parser_f
>       return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\train\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 463, in _read
>       data = parser.read(nrows)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\train\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py",
>   line 1169, in read
>       df = DataFrame(col_dict, columns=columns, index=index)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\train\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py",
>   line 411, in **init**
>       mgr = init_dict(data, index, columns, dtype=dtype)
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\train\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\internals\construction.py",
>   line 236, in init_dict
>       if missing.any() and not is_integer_dtype(dtype):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\train\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py",
>   line 11723, in logical_func
>       filter_type="bool",
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\train\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py",
>   line 4086, in _reduce
>       with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
>
> File
>   "C:\Users\train\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\numeric.py",
>   line 3055, in **init**
>
> NameError: name '_Unspecified' is not defined

Comment: can you show us the whole traceback?

Comment: Yes, please see edited post

Comment: are you using some virtual environment?

Comment: No using anaconda 4.8.2

Comment: I had same issue. I uninstall and re-install padas. The issue happened after install other packages so I re-install padas and solved it.